# Adding a title below the logo

Tags: child-theme, title

I need to add a site title as a text below the logo for a site. The title should be `<h2>` tag. The theme allows either image or text, but not both.

Comment: If you can post relevant part of the code from inside your theme's `header.php` you will be more likely to receive a more helpful answer. The portion of the code you are looking for will look similar to the place in the HTML where the image is added when you "view source" in your browser. It probably says something like `header`, `logo` or `site-title` in the `id` or `class` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to customize the `header.php` of your theme (from **Appearancece > Editor**), I recommend you create a child theme first and then find **#logo** within the header.php and add the title below the logo.

I cannot show you exactly how since I don't know the `header.php` of your theme, but after you find the where the logo is generated **#logo** you will know where to place your title.

```
<h2>Your title</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have child theme created. what code I should add in child theme. I have two files in child theme sytle.css and functions.php. Do you want me to share the header.php file of the parent theme as text?

Comment: You should also have the header.php on your child theme folder, yes, you can share it with me and I will point out the line for you, but you can also simply check the code and search for where #logo is generated, but whatever :)

Comment: Here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/weiclbhrto025lx/header.txt?dl=0

Comment: Great, find line **49**, it's above **<!-- #logo -->**. Right now it looks like this **</div>**, you will replace that line with **</div><h2>My tittle</h2>**, after that your site will look like this: https://i.imgur.com/ytV484n.png

Comment: Added but the title is on the top. Please check https://imgur.com/a/0RRZApD

Comment: I think it was my mistake, it's on line 48 form your last picture, and it should be **<h2>My tittle</h2></div>** the closing div at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear that, please mark the answer as solved if it helped :D

Comment: sorry to say, I don't know how to mark this as closed.